# How to use runit to supervise a rails microservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, runit

I'm attempting to do some continuous deployment of some rails micro-services on my ubuntu server, I'm thinking maybe runit would be a good idea to supervise these processes, then use migrations in chef to update the microservice  - but I'm stuck getting one service to work. Basically the installation seems to work in the chef deploy but the app doesn't start and is not listening on 3000 ( doing a manual start from the deployment folder does work after killing the server.pid )

This is a cleanly provisioned machine and the only rails app on the box - so the error mentioned in the log I think is symptom of how I'm attempting to start it.

Any tips on how this might work (alternatives) appreciated!

Template

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
exec chpst -u root:root nohup rails server &
```

It doesn't look like nohup is the way to do this - the log file produces this. I don't understand how a server is already running - the first log entry says its already running... however a

```
2015-10-14_22:15:24.87117 A server is already running. Check     /opt/deploy/releases/39b30d7738bfba76462e257eb15100e1bea4edf0/tmp/pids/server.pid.
2015-10-14_22:15:25.32768 => Booting Thin
2015-10-14_22:15:25.32771 => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
2015-10-14_22:15:25.32772 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-10-14_22:15:25.32772 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-10-14_22:15:25.32773 Exiting
```

this repeats several times... until this error no longer logs.

```
2015-10-14_22:15:17.16187 A server is already running. Check     /opt/deploy/releases/39b30d7738bfba76462e257eb15100e1bea4edf0/tmp/pids/server.pid.
2015-10-14_22:15:17.60398 => Booting Thin
2015-10-14_22:15:17.60401 => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development    on http://localhost:3000
2015-10-14_22:15:17.60402 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-10-14_22:15:17.60403 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-10-14_22:15:17.60404 Exiting
```

if I ps aux | grep rails it l lots of these entries

```
root     17709  3.6  1.4  93692 29468 ?       Rl   23:18   0:01 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 bin/rails server
root     17713  3.7  1.4  92112 28684 ?        Rl   23:18   0:01 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 bin/rails server
root     17717  3.7  1.3  91844 27696 ?        Rl   23:18   0:00 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 bin/rails server
root     17721  3.5  1.2  90164 26072 ?        Rl   23:18   0:00 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 bin/rails server
root     17725  3.6  1.2  90164 26192 ?        Rl   23:18   0:00 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 bin/rails server
```

Recipe

```
deploy_revision("/opt/deploy") do
  revision "master"
  repository "https://repo" 
  user "root"
  action :deploy
  shallow_clone true
  keep_releases 3
  rollback_on_error true  # remove release if callbacks failed
  migrate true
  migration_command "rake db:migrate"
  before_migrate do
    execute "bundle install" do
      command "bundle install"
      cwd  "#{release_path}"
      user "root" 
    end
  end

  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink.clear
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
end

runit_service "auth" do
  run_template_name "myapp"
  log_template_name "myapp"
  options({
    :app_env => "development",
    :app_home => "/opt/deploy/current",
    :data_dir => "/opt/deploy/data"
  })
  retries 3
  retry_delay 5
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `nohup` or the `&` in the `runit` script. You're probably just confusing the monitor daemon. Have you tried without them?

Comment: you're right - it doesn't need nohup or & - thanks for clearing it up